# Issue with Cisco WebEx: "atinst.exe - Entry Point Not Found"

Tags: windows-8.1, webex

For some reason Cisco WebEx client stopped working on my Windows 8.1 Pro x64 machine and it looks as follows whenever I attempt to join the meeting:

[image]

So it just freeze on 10% and error message says:

> **atinst.exe - Entry Point Not Found**
>
> The procedure entry point _itoa_s could not be located in the dynamic
>   link library C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll

The library mentioned in error message exists in C:\Windows\System32 and has the following version:

[image]

I tried to reinstall the client more than once as well as clean WebEx folders in %AppData% locations, but this did not work. The only way I can join the WebEx meeting now is if I download the meeting file and join the meeting using it. The only prior change which I can possibly link to this problem is removal some old version of Java (I now have Java 8 update 51 x64 and x32 installed) but not sure if it is related with this WebEx issue.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly missing the Visual C++ Redistributable library that was used to compile the Cisco WebEx client and especially atinst.exe.
Serious products are expected to install their
Visual C++ library version when they are installed, but possibly this
wasn't done in your case.

Use the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on atinst.exe to find the DLLs that are used
by atinst.exe. The DLL names you are looking may be similar `MSVCRT*.DLL` or
`MSVCP*.dll` or `MSVCR*.dll`. The Dependency Walker will give an error message
for each missing DLL, which you can then use to identify the missing runtime
library (or I can help you with it).

For downloading the right library, see this Microsoft website :
[The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003).

Comment: Could the masked under-voter justify himself? In my opinion my answer is quite plausible as a solution.

Comment: I haven't tried Dependency Walker yet, but I think my issues maybe related with symptoms I mentioned in the comment to other solution proposed above.

Comment: If your Windows is sick, you can refresh it without loosing your programs and data (take backups anyway). See [Non-destructive reinstall of Windows 8 and 8.1](https://www.winhelp.us/non-destructive-reinstall-of-windows-8-and-8-1.html).

Comment: I can see in CBS.log references to the Windows Store. You might try the advice for [Fixing Windows Store Problems](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-81/three-options-fixing-windows-store-problems) before refreshing Windows. If the problems with atinst.exe continue, use my above advice to analyze, but "sfc /scannow" must return no errors first.

Answer (score 0):

The [_itoa_s function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0we9x30h%28v=VS.120%29.aspx) (Convert an integer to a string) is located in the `MSVCRT.dll` and not `combase.dll`.

Looks like our tool doesn't support the secure CRT and Windows 8.1 correctly. Make sure you use the latest version. Also run `sfc /scannow` or `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` to detect corrupted Windows files.

Comment: I tried to use sfc /scannow but get the following error: "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
supported in offline servicing scenarios." And DISM option does not work for me with error " "DISM does not support servicing Windows PE with the /Online option." It seems to me that I know the cause of the latter (ReFS on non mirrored volumes registry key was created) but unclear how to fix it.

Comment: Better post CBS.Log for us to see.

Comment: why do you run DISM from WinPE and not from the running Windows? Use those commands to dump the SR output into a smaller txt file and here you can see what can't be repaired: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/928228

Comment: @magicandre1981 So I think I give up and moving to Windows 10 on this occasion. I tried Refresh and see that it does not work too along with System Restore... I tried to rebuild WMI store and looks like it done more harm than good as now even Event Viewer does not work too :-/... Though let me share CBS.log while I not formatted C drive...

Comment: @harrymc CBS.log - http://1drv.ms/1Kg8RBD

Comment: your utc.app.json and telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json are modified, but this is expexted: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3068708: *"The two files are marked as static files in the update. When an advanced user runs the System File Checker Tool (sfc.exe), the files are unintentionally flagged as corrupted. There is no impact or actual corruption on a device that is running this update, and this issue will be fixed in a later service update."* So you have no damaged file.

Comment: `Looks like our tool doesn't support the secure CRT` are you with Cisco? if so please disclose your affiliation.

Answer (score -1):

This is what's going on: `atinst.exe` was built liked to the `_itoa_s()` function which is part of the MSVC runtime (`MSVCRT.dll`) but the OS (`Windows 8.1`) dynamically links the application to `combase.dll` instead, which has certain entries i.e. `_itoa_s` redirected to other dlls i.e. `MSVCRT.dll`

dll redirection is the MS strategy to deal with the dll versioning nightmare

your problem should be fixed installing the right MSVC runtime.

also you can get `Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them` but that doesn't mean that message is related to this issue.

Comment: unexplained downvotes do not make  much sense....right?